# Using LIKE in mySQL WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am trying to SELECT data WHERE the Name contains **Christina** using the following query, but it is returning all data, not only **Christina**.

```
SELECT a.id_transaksi, a.total_harga, (
        SELECT c.id_transfer
        FROM tbl_transfer c
        WHERE c.id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi
        ) AS id_transfer, (
        SELECT d.nama
        FROM tbl_costumer d
        WHERE d.username = a.username
        ) AS nama_costumer
FROM tbl_faktur a, tbl_transfer c, tbl_costumer d
WHERE a.konfirm_user = 1
    AND d.nama LIKE '%christina%'
GROUP BY a.id_transaksi
ORDER BY a.id_transaksi DESC
```

Comment: You need `join` conditions between the tables.  Simple rule:  *Never use a comma in the `from` clause; always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need subqueries. `join` the tables with the appropriate conditions and it should work.

```
SELECT
a.id_transaksi, a.total_harga,  
c.id_transfer id_transfer,
d.nama as nama_costumer
FROM tbl_faktur a 
JOIN tbl_transfer c on c.id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi
JOIN tbl_costumer d on d.username = a.username
WHERE a.konfirm_user = 1 
AND d.nama LIKE '%christina%'
ORDER BY a.id_transaksi DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only filter on the 'top-level' query is `c.id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi`. You'll need to `join` against `tbl_costumer`, then filter on that to see the result you're expecting. I don't know the relationships between your customer/transfer table, but there's likely a `customer_id` on `tbl_transfer`, which should get you to the costumer table.

Comment: yes, i tried it befor, but it was returning all data, but in the column nama_costumer only display Christina, and others where NULL. how to not display the nama_costumer which has NULL value ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, just adding EXSIST to WHERE clause...

```
SELECT a.id_transaksi, a.total_harga, a.total_berat, a.kurir, a.servis, a.resi, a.konfirm_user, a.konfirm_admin, a.date_user, a.ongkir, (   
                SELECT  c.id_transfer
                FROM tbl_transfer c
                WHERE c.id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi
                ) AS id_transfer, (

                SELECT  d.nama
                FROM tbl_costumer d
                WHERE d.username = a.username
                ) AS nama_costumer, (

                SELECT  d.provinsi_asal
                FROM tbl_costumer d
                WHERE d.username = a.username
                ) AS provinsi_asal, (

                SELECT  d.kota_asal
                FROM tbl_costumer d
                WHERE d.username = a.username
                ) AS kota_asal, (

                SELECT  d.alamat
                FROM tbl_costumer d
                WHERE d.username = a.username
                ) AS alamat, (

                SELECT  d.tlp
                FROM tbl_costumer d
                WHERE d.username = a.username
                ) AS tlp

            FROM tbl_faktur a,  tbl_transfer c, tbl_costumer d
            WHERE a.konfirm_user=1 AND exists (SELECT d.nama from tbl_costumer d  where a.username=d.username and d.nama like '%$keyword%') 
            GROUP BY a.id_transaksi
            ORDER BY a.id_transaksi DESC
```